# Was the Chocobi (チョコビ) snack from Shin Chan fictional or did it exist before Shin Chan?

Tags: merchandise, crayon-shin-chan

If you watched the Shin Chan anime series you will know what I'm talking about. (I don't know if Chocobi appears in the manga, too.) Was Chocobi an existing snack that just appeared in the Shin Chan series? Or was it invented with the series and later produced as a real snack for merchandise?

Answer (score 3):

According to various Japanese sources ([Japanese Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%AF%E3%83%AC%E3%83%A8%E3%83%B3%E3%81%97%E3%82%93%E3%81%A1%E3%82%83%E3%82%93#.E3.82.B3.E3.83.A9.E3.83.9C.E3.83.AC.E3.83.BC.E3.82.B7.E3.83.A7.E3.83.B3), [NicoNicoPedia](http://dic.nicovideo.jp/a/%E3%83%81%E3%83%A7%E3%82%B3%E3%83%93), [pixiv dic](http://dic.pixiv.net/a/%E3%83%81%E3%83%A7%E3%82%B3%E3%83%93), [Geocities JP](http://2nd.geocities.jp/tyomo_pi5/meshi/chocobi/tyocobi.htm)), **the Chocobi snack was originally came from *Crayon Shin-chan***.

However, according to the interview with Mitsuru Hongo (Director of *Crayon Shin-chan*'s anime), it was based from Lotte's *Koala's March*.

[image: Lotte's Koala's March]

... until 1993, when Lotte did a collaboration with *Crayon Shin-chan* to produce a peanuts chocolate flavored snack with 2 types: Chocobi, and Royal Chocobi (with almond). However, they're pretty much different from the one in anime. <sup>Couldn't find any images of them.</sup>

Later on, Orion also produced Chocobi snack with star-shaped, but the package was totally different.

[image: Orion's Chocobi]

Bandai also produced Chocobi snack, but instead of star-shaped, it's a biscuit stick. The package was also totally different.

[image: Bandai's Chocobi]

Moving forward to 2006, Tohato released a real Chocobi snack.

[image: Tohato's Chocobi]

Lastly, since 2014, Morinaga did a collaboration with the movie to produce Chocobi Ice.

[image: Morinaga's Chocobi Ice]

Answer (score 1):

When the manga version of *Shin-chan* was published, he always ate Koala's March, not Chocobi.

When the anime version is adapted, there is a trademark and sponsor problem. If Shin-chan eats Koala's March and the CM shows for a different snack, it will become a huge problem.

Thus, the anime director creates a new snack with non-existence name.

After the anime aired, the manga version also changed the snack to Chocobi too.
Snack for Shin-chan in the manga is different between first few volumes and later episodes.

This kind of problem is happening for many anime too. For example, in the manga version of Bakuman, they talk about Shonen Jump. But in the anime version, the name was changed to Shonen Jack.

Answer (score -2):

[image]

Chocobi (チョコビ Chokobi) is a fictional chocolate star-shape snack brand favoured by Shin. **It is a famous brand in real-life and continues to do so via the anime's popularity**.

so your last statement is the correct one.

Comment: Well, this says the brand _continues to exist_ due to the anime's popularity. It says nothing about the product's origin — I could find this much with a quick Google search, and I assume the OP did too...

Comment: @JNat I think the "is a fictional..." is probably supposed to be "was originally a fictional...".  Google searches for japanese sites pull up phrases akin to the latter, but I'm having trouble identifying a particularly definitive source (a date when it was first sold, compared to the first episode it appeared in, would be perfect).